# Can Fine Uploader's drag and drop work with Outlook attachments

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader 3.3 with jQuery wrapper.  The drag and drop works great if the files are from the desktop.  But, I cannot get the drag and drop to work with attachments from Outlook.

Can Fine Uploader receive attachments from Outlook via drag and drop?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.  Please see [a similar question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/441747/dragging-attachments-from-outlook-into-applications).

A quick workaround would be to drag the attachment to the desktop, and then drag it into your web page.

Comment: The workaround is what we are using now.  But, it is not quick with the number of emails that we receive and with the number of attachments that are in each email. The quick solution would be to just drag it from the email into our Fine Uploader drop zone.  I checked your possible link and it doesn't look like it's a solution--but thanks!

Comment: My answer is: there is no way to do this.  You must drag onto the desktop first.  The link I provided explains why this is true.